# Get Value from Object from List<object> with Expressions

Tags: c#, expression

I'm just getting started with expression and simply do not get ahead.
I have an XML file with rules which I parse and wants to transform in Expressions.

My problem is this, i have a context :

```
public class KnxObject
{
    public KnxObject() { }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

List<KnxObjects> knxObjectContext = new List<KnxObject>();
string address = "foo";
string value = "bar";

var boolean = knxObjectContext.Where(it => it.Address == address).ElementAt(0).Value == value;
```

How do I create this query with System.Linq.Expressions?

Many thanks!
TimT

Comment: What are "transfer expression" and "object... is set to 1"? Could you post a pseudo-code?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems did you run into when creating expressions? One thing that can make this easier is assigning a lambda expression to a variable of type `Expression<Func<...>>` (the easy way of creating expression trees) and inspecting the resulting object with a debugger, or if you're using Linqpad, just `.Dump()`ing it will give you a visual representation.

Comment: I have created the following expression with func, but how do i create an expression tree from this?

Expression<Func<List<KnxObject>, string, KnxObject>> expr = (x,y) => x.Where(i => i.Address == y).First();